# Calling function in function breaks template

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm currently trying to build a simple forum. I'm using a function `List_Category()` to get the categories, then I am calling another function `List_SubCategory($id)` inside `List_Category()`, to get the categories subcategories. However, I'm having a trouble, because if I `echo` the result from `List_SubCategory($id)` it makes the subcategories to appear above the content box, instead of inside of it (which to me, makes no sense!)

How it should look (but with more than 1 result):
[image]

How it looks if I use `echo` in `List_SubCategory($id)`:
[image]

The functions:

```
public function List_Category() {

    $GetCat = $this->dbc->prepare("SELECT id,name,type,minrank,mini_icon FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC");
    if($GetCat->execute()) {

        $GetCat->bind_result($catid, $catname, $cattype, $catminrank, $caticon);
        $GetCat->store_result();

        if($GetCat->num_rows >= 1) {

            while($GetCat->fetch()) {
                echo '<h3 id="CatTitle"><a href="#"><i class="'.$caticon.'"></i> '.$catname.'</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="CatMin-'.$catid.'"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" id="CategoryMinim"></i></a></h3>
                    <div id="CategoryBlock" class="Cat-'.$catid.'">
                        '.$this->List_SubCategory($catid).'
                    </div>
                    <br style="clear:both">';
            }

        }

    } else {

        return BoardTemplate::ThrowNewAlert("error", $GetCat->error);

    }

}

public function List_SubCategory($id) {

    $GetSub = $this->dbc->prepare("SELECT id,name,attach_id FROM subcategories WHERE attach_id = ? ORDER BY id ASC");
    $GetSub->bind_param("i", $id);
    if($GetSub->execute()) {

        $GetSub->bind_result($subid, $subname, $subattach);
        $GetSub->store_result();

        if($GetSub->num_rows >= 1) {


            while($GetSub->fetch()) {

            echo '<div id="CatSep" style="position: relative;">
                        <i class="fa fa-comments-o" id="ReadStatus"></i>  <div class="Title"><a href="#">'.$subname.'</a></div>
                        <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/78/783bd2db99ca87c20c23b2ff59427fdd8aff8329_full.jpg" class="SizeTinyAvatar" id="CatAva" style="float:right;" />
                        <div class="Desc">
                            <div style="float: right" id="fr"><b>Latest:</b> <a href="#">Welcome to your first fucking...</a></div><br style="clear:both">
                            <div style="float: right" id="fr">Posted by <a href="#">Kah!</a>, 2 days ago</div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="StatsHelp">
                            <div id="CatStats">10<br>Topics</div>
                            <div id="CatStats">10<br>Posts</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
            }




        } else {
            echo "no cat";
        }



    }

}
```

My current theory is it's broken because `List_Category()` is echoing it's result, which `List_SubCategory($id)` is doing as well, so it's echoing inside an echo. Func-ception?

I can ensure there is nothing wrong with my html or my css. If I replace `echo` in `List_SubCategory($id)` with `return`, it looks like in the first picture, but then it seems to ignore the `while()` because it's only giving me the first row in the database.

This was tricky to explain. But any help is appreciated. I have no idea how I should make it look as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `echo` in the second `List_SubCategory()` is finished before the `echo` in `List_Category()` function.

Instead of echo the string directly, you should write it to a variable and return this variable at the end of the `List_SubCategory()` function. As you already described, you should not place the return inside the while.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried assigning the echo to a variable, and then i returned the variable outside the while loop. However this does only return the last row in the database, and not both of them (as there are 2). If i place the return inside the while loop, well, it only returns the first row.

Comment: You have to define the variable at the top of the function (`$html = "";`) and append it in the while (`$html += "[your html code]";`), otherwise you override the variable each time.

Comment: If I do that, it just prints a "0"

Comment: Do you return the variable at the end of the function? can you paste your new code in here?

Comment: My mistake. You have to append the variable with `$html .= "[your html code]";`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would never have figured it out myself

Comment: One more thing. You should also `return` "no cat" instead of `echo`, otherwise the same "bug" would occur there. ;)

Comment: Yes I figured that out myself, danke :)